# Remove duplicates from ONE column not row

Tags: r

I am trying to remove duplicate emails in a column of my data.frame using duplicate() and distinct() in R however, I do not need it to delete the whole row just the duplicate email addresses in that column. Is there anyway to do that using these? Or is there another way to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
patient2 <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope', "Mycroft Holmes", "Carrie 
Bird", "Carrie Bird", "Marcus Quimby", "Jennifer Poe", "Donna Moon")
salary2 <- c(21000, 23400, 26800, 40000, 50000, 33000, 24000, 75000, 90000)
email2 <- c("doe@gmail.com", "gynn@gmail.com", "hope@gmail.com", 
"holmes@gmail.com", "bird@gmail.com", "bird@gmail.com", "quimby@gmail.com", 
"poe@gmail.com", "moon@gmail.com")
startdate2 <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14', '2020-7-19', 
'2019-4-20', '2018-2-13', '2017-4-21', '2019-6-10', '2010-9-19'))

patient.data_2 <- data.frame(patient2, salary2, email2, startdate2)
print(patient.data_2)


patient2<fctr> salary2<dbl> email2<fctr> startdate2<date>
John Doe       21000    doe@gmail.com       2010-11-01  
Peter Gynn     23400    gynn@gmail.com      2008-03-25  
Jolie Hope     26800    hope@gmail.com      2007-03-14  
Mycroft Holmes 40000    holmes@gmail.com    2020-07-19  
Carrie Bird    50000    bird@gmail.com      2019-04-20  
Carrie Bird    33000    bird@gmail.com      2018-02-13  
Marcus Quimby  24000    quimby@gmail.com    2017-04-21  
Jennifer Poe   75000    poe@gmail.com       2019-06-10  
Donna Moon     90000    moon@gmail.com      2010-09-19    

extracted <- merged_data[!duplicated(merged_data$email), ]
extracted
```

> All I would like to do is remove the extra duplicate email for the person
> Carrie Bird. Not the entire row because the date is different. I tried using
> duplicated() and distinct() and both removed the entire row.

Comment: Can you add some of the code you've tried using so far to your answer?

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `duplicated` function:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4))
dat$a[duplicated(dat$a)] <- NA
dat
#>     a
#> 1   1
#> 2  NA
#> 3   2
#> 4  NA
#> 5   3
#> 6  NA
#> 7   4
#> 8  NA
#> 9  NA
#> 10 NA
```

Comment: Do I have to replace it with NA? I would just like to remove the duplicates from the dataframe and leave it blank when i write into an excel form?

Comment: Instead of assigning `NA`, just replace it with anything you want to keep. If you just want an empty space, then  `dat$a[duplicated(dat$a)] <- ""`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer or clarify your question if this not fully resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% 
      mutate(a = replace(a, duplicated(a), NA))
```